# Retaining parent slugs in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3, slug, custom-routes

I'm experimenting with SEO friendly URL's in CakePHP as efficiently as I can, I've managed to use the current format, each example uses function view($slug) except for the first example which uses function index().

> /categories/
>
> /categories/books/
>
> /categories/books/it-and-computing/

But what if IT & Computing has a sub-category "Web Development"? I'd like the URL to become:

> /categories/books/it-and-computing/web-development/

I'm not sure how to do this without creating too many routes. Here is my route code so far:

> Router::connect('/categories/', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'index'));
>
> Router::connect('/categories/:slug', 
>          array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view'), 
>          array('pass' => array('slug'))
>   );
>
> Router::connect('/categories/:parent/:slug',
>          array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view'),
>          array('pass' => array('parent', 'slug'))
>   );

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Kind Regards

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

```
// in routes.php
Router::connect('/categories/:row:lastslash',array('controller' => 'settings', 'action' => 'show',),array(
      'pass'=>array('row'),
      'row'=>'.*?',
      'lastslash'=>'\/?'
));

//in controller
function show($row = ""){
  if($row){
    $categories = split('/',$row);

    ?><pre><? print_r($categories);?></pre><?die();
  }else{
    die('do something else');
  }
}
```

/categories/books/computing/web-development/cakephp/

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => books
    [1] => computing
    [2] => web-development
    [3] => cakephp
)
```

/categories/

result:

```
do something else
```

/categories/books

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => books
)
```

Comment: I am also hoping that this question will get more answers. Something that works for n-level subcategories.

Comment: The above isn't going to work, I think you've misunderstood the question. The website needs to keep the full history in the URL somewhat like a bread crumb. /categories/books/computing/web-development/cakephp/ etc

Comment: This looks like it is exactly what I'm looking for, I can't try it now but I will later. Thanks a lot sukinsan :) I'd "upvote" you but I'm too new to the website. Cheers